# Prevent Form Action From Changing URL After File Upload

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple form in my Spring MVC project that handles a file upload.

form.jsp

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" id="form">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Because of the form's action however, I am redirected to `localhost:8080/myApp/upload` rather than `localhost:8080/myApp/form` as specified in my `@Controller`

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "${context}/upload", headers = "content-type=multipart/*")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
    //do some upload stuff
    model.addAttribute("uploadSuccess", "Upload Successful.");
    return "/form";
}
```

Is it possible to prevent only the form action's redirection, but still retain the value `${context}/upload` so that my Controller method gets called? I need my page to land back on `myApp/form` because this particualr url makes a call to a separate Controller method that retrieves some data

Note that I don't wish to rename my jsp file to 'upload.jsp' and I don't want to make an AJAX Post (Thanks for nothing IE9). Any thoughts mates?

Comment: does you solved it?  i have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for my exact case on **17.5.3 Redirecting to views** from [Spring's Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

> It is sometimes desirable to issue an HTTP redirect back to the
>   client, before the view is rendered. This is desirable, for example,
>   when one controller has been called with POST data, and the response
>   is actually a delegation to another controller (for example on a
>   successful form submission). In this case, a normal internal forward
>   will mean that the other controller will also see the same POST data,
>   which is potentially problematic if it can confuse it with other
>   expected data.

This can be done with the following:

```
return "redirect:/form";
```

A nice benefit to the `redirect` is that it prevents the user from accidentally re-`POST`ing the same data by performing a refresh. The refresh forces a `GET` of the result page, not a resend of the initial POST data.

**UPDATE:**

The default `redirect:/view` will append your model attributes to your URL as query params. This may be undesirable in some cases as it could expose sensitive information to the user. Utilize [`RedirectAttributes addFlashAttribute(String attributeName, Object attributeValue)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) method to in order to store Flash Attributes that will be used to store attributes when redirected from one URL to another (Success/Failure messages, etc.)